# Select where count of one field is greater than one

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM db.table 
 WHERE COUNT(someField) > 1
```

How can I achieve this in MySql?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Use the `HAVING`, not `WHERE` clause, for aggregate result comparison.

Taking the query at face value:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM db.table 
HAVING COUNT(someField) > 1
```

Ideally, there should be a `GROUP BY` defined for proper valuation in the `HAVING` clause, but [MySQL does allow hidden columns from the GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)...

Is this in preparation for a unique constraint on `someField`?  Looks like it should be...

Comment: Needs a `GROUP BY` surely (unless this is some MySQL non standard thing)?

Comment: @Martin Smith: Took the query at face value; addressed GROUP BY issue (incl. hidden columns feature).

Comment: "Looks like it should be..." Why? I am in need of education on this :)

Comment: So this will return the whole table if it contains more than 2 non null `someField` values or an empty result set if it doesn't.

Comment: @Dave: If you were in a position where you had to periodically check & correct bad data, wouldn't you want to stop the situation from happening in the first place?  MySQL implements a unique constraint as an index - for more info see the [CREATE INDEX documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Comment: @Martin Smith: I think it's a poor example, and there's no details currently to go on.

Comment: I understand your original comment now. I thought there was something special about the query that I wasn't getting. Thanks.

Comment: But...does this work when a less-trivial statement is needed?  For instance, `HAVING COUNT(someField) > 1 AND someOtherField = 5 AND thirdThing IN (SELECT ...)`?  If not, I think @dandy_sql has the better answer.

Comment: Error: Column (someField) is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 46):

Here you go:

```
SELECT Field1, COUNT(Field1)
  FROM Table1 
 GROUP BY Field1
HAVING COUNT(Field1) > 1
ORDER BY Field1 desc
```

Answer (score 22):

```
SELECT username, numb from(
Select username, count(username) as numb from customers GROUP BY username ) as my_table
WHERE numb > 3
```

Comment: the only caveat here (at least in 5.1.46-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)) is that "Every derived table must have its own alias", that will make you sql look like: SELECT username, numb from(
Select username, count(username) as numb from customers GROUP BY username ) as my_table
WHERE numb > 3

Comment: This is useful when I group by multiple columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

You can also do this with a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM db.table t1
JOIN db.table t2 ON t1.someField = t2.someField AND t1.pk != t2.pk
```

Answer (score 5):

One way

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM db.table t1
WHERE exists 
      (SELECT *
      FROM db.table t2 
      where t1.pk != t2.pk 
      and t1.someField = t2.someField)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table]
where field IN (
    select field
    from [Table]
    group by field
    having COUNT(field)>1 )
```

Answer (score 2):

I give an example up on Group By between two table in Sql:

`Select cn.name,ct.name,count(ct.id) totalcity
from city ct left join country cn on ct.countryid = cn.id
Group By cn.name,ct.name
Having totalcity > 2`

---

Answer (score 2):

For me, Not having a group by just returned empty result. So i guess having a group by for the having statement is pretty important

Answer (score 1):

As OMG Ponies stated, the having clause is what you are after.  However, if you were hoping that you would get discrete rows instead of a summary (the "having" creates a summary) - it cannot be done in a single statement.  You must use two statements in that case.

Comment: Not entirely true - use the GROUP BY to manipulate what the HAVING is using.

Answer (score 1):

Without **HAVING**

```
SELECT COL,TOTAL
FROM (SELECT SPORT, COUNT(COL) AS TOTAL FROM db.table GROUP BY SPORT)
WHERE TOTAL > 100 ORDER BY TOTAL
```

or with **HAVING**

```
SELECT COL, COUNT(COL) AS TOTAL
FROM db.table
GROUP BY SPORT HAVING TOTAL > 100
ORDER BY COL
```

Answer (score -2):

It should also be mentioned that the "pk" should be a key field.
The self-join

```
SELECT t1.* FROM db.table t1
JOIN db.table t2 ON t1.someField = t2.someField AND t1.pk != t2.pk
```

by Bill Karwin give you all the records that are duplicates which is what I wanted. Because some have more than two,
you can get the same record more than once. I wrote all to another table with the same fields to get rid of the same records by key fields suppression.
I tried

`SELECT * FROM db.table HAVING COUNT(someField) > 1`

above first.
The data returned from it give only one of the duplicates, less than 1/2 of what this gives you but the count is good if that is all you want.

Comment: This is not really an answer.