# How do you retrieve a photo or photos containing only one tagged user using either FQL or Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags, facebook-fql, photos

I have tried accomplish this using both FQL and the Graph API.

I began by trying this FQL call:

```
$fql = "SELECT pic, src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me())";
```

From this I receive results that include images containing a tag of the given user (in this case: me()). However, these images may include more than one tagged user. I was hoping to work around this issue by using the SQL HAVING clause along with COUNT (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3710501/1406986). Unfortunately I don't think FQL supports this functionality because when I attempted this call:

```
$fql = "SELECT pic, src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag HAVING COUNT(subject) = 1";
```

I recived an error from Facebook. Please correct me if FQL does in fact support this functionality.

In attempt to tackle this using the Graph API I made the following request:

```
$userPics = $facebook->api('/me/photos');
```

This returns the user's photos, however, from this point I was forced to iterate over every photo looking for ones that only contain one tag. I found this to be impractical if, for instance, I need to find an image for each of a user's friends that only contains their friend and no others. To do this I would need to retrieve all of each of their friend's photos individually and then iterate over all of them.

I'm still searching for a good solution. Please post your ideas and solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have managed to create a FQL for this problem, but it's not pretty at all

```
SELECT object_id, pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN
  (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag 
    WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me()) 
    AND NOT (pid IN 
      (SELECT pid  FROM photo_tag WHERE pid IN 
        (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me()) 
      AND subject != me())
    )
  )
```

**Explanation:**

The first one is pretty simple, get the photo_tags of the current user

```
SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me()
```

The next one I joined the same table, but this time I wanted the photos where I was with someone

```
SELECT pid  FROM photo_tag WHERE pid IN 
  (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me()) 
AND subject != me()
```

The I joined the same table again (yes 3 joins with same table), but this time I wanted the photo_tags where I was the subject **AND** that weren't on the list I got before (the photos where I was the subject with someone), so this query returns all the photo_tags where the user is the only one tagged in that photo

```
SELECT pid FROM photo_tag 
WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me()) 
   AND NOT (pid IN 
     (SELECT pid  FROM photo_tag WHERE pid IN 
        (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me()) 
      AND subject != me())
   )
```

The last addition to the query was just a join to get the info from the photo table of the photos were I was the only one tagged

```
SELECT object_id, pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN
  (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag 
    WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me()) 
    AND NOT (pid IN 
      (SELECT pid  FROM photo_tag WHERE pid IN 
        (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me()) 
      AND subject != me())
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution Fabio! I took a look at this in the FQL explorer and it works nicely. Now, if only users would fully tag photos containing multiple people or if there were some way to filter out those images as well...haha