# Count rows in table where field is duplicated more than 5 times

Tags: sql, count

Got a list of user accounts in a table, accompanying them are IPs.

I need to run a query that shows only the rows that have more than 5 of the same IP.

I did have a query, but I've lost it

(I need ID, USERNAME and LAST_IP returned) - LAST_IP is also where the IPs are stored to do the count

Comment: You are looking for `HAVING COUNT(someField)>5` http://stackoverflow.com/a/3710501/1618257

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've tried so far, nobody will do the work for you, they'll help fix an issue if your code/SQL isn't working correctly.

Comment: I cant find anything on it though, so im asking for rough help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
declare @table table (user_id int identity(1, 1), user_name varchar(100), last_ip varchar(50))

insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('joe moe', '192.168.0.XX')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('xyz', '192.168.0.XX')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('dummy', '192.168.0.XX')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('harry potter', '192.168.0.XX')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('he who should not be named', '192.168.0.XX')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('times square', '192.168.0.XX')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('user1', '192.168.0.YY')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('user2', '192.168.0.YY')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('user3', '192.168.0.YY')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('user4', '192.168.0.YY')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('user5', '192.168.0.YY')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('user6', '192.168.0.YY')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('tom dick harry', '192.168.0.ZZ')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('peter pan', '192.168.0.ZZ')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('humpty dumpty', '192.168.0.ZZ')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('red riding hood', '192.168.0.ZZ')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('tintin', '192.168.0.ZZ')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('mickey mouse', '192.168.0.ZZ')
insert into @table (user_name, last_ip) values ('only user', '192.168.0.AA')

select a.* from @table a
inner join
(
    select last_ip, count(*) as cnt from @table
    group by last_ip
    having count(*) > 5
) allCounts
on a.last_ip = allCounts.last_ip
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to do something like this:

SELECT ID, USERNAME, LAST_IP, count(*) as CNT from TABLE_NAME group by ID, USERNAME, LAST_IP HAVING count(*) > 5 ORDER BY CNT DESC

Comment: I tried this, but it does not count up the IP addresses