# Basic SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ms-access

Shown below is the SQL database and query I am a bit stuck on creating. I'm just unsure on how to specify that the results needs to show people who have played in more than two matches.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT playerno
FROM PLAYERS, MATCHES
WHERE PLAYERS.playerno = MATCHES.playerno
AND town = ‘Manchester’;
```

---

You are given the following tennis database.

```
PLAYERS (playerno, name, leagueno, year_of_birth, town, street, year_joined, postcode)
TEAMS (teamno, playerno, division)
MATCHES ( matchno, teamno, playerno, sets_won, sets_lost)
PENALTIES (paymentno, playerno, pendate, amount)
```

Q) Find the player number of players who appear in more than two matches
and live in ‘Manchester’

Comment: So which version of sql are you using? You should only tag the correct one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select where count of one field is greater than one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710483/select-where-count-of-one-field-is-greater-than-one)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151401/sql-query-for-finding-records-where-count-1) question seems to address the same thing.

Comment: What @Andrew is referring to is that you tagged both mysql and sql-server (totally different servers) and that could have effect on the answers!

Comment: @davejal Okay, will bare this in mind next time I ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of approaches you can use.

One is to make use of an *aggregate* function and a `GROUP BY` clause to "collapse" rows with identical values.  We'll assume that we'd determine that a player was in more than two matches if there are at least three rows in the `matches` table for that player.

(Also, ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation, and use the `JOIN` keyword instead.)

Current query:

```
SELECT p.playerno
  FROM PLAYERS p
  JOIN MATCHES m 
    ON m.playerno = p.playerno
 WHERE p.town = 'Manchester'
```

Adding a `GROUP BY` clause to collapse rows that have the same value for `playerno`.

```
SELECT p.playerno
     , COUNT(1)
  FROM PLAYERS p
  JOIN MATCHES m 
    ON m.playerno = p.playerno
 WHERE p.town = 'Manchester'
 GROUP BY p.playerno
 ORDER BY p.playerno
```

The `ORDER BY` isn't strictly necessary, but it makes the returned result more deterministic. (Absent an ORDER BY clause, MySQL is free to return the rows in whatever order it chooses.)

The next trick is to reference the result of the aggregate function (`COUNT(1)`) in a `HAVING` clause. This can't go into the `WHERE` clause, because the predicates in the WHERE clause get evaluated as the rows are accessed. We want to apply a predicate *after* the rows have been accessed, and the result of the aggregate has been determined.

```
SELECT p.playerno
  FROM PLAYERS p
  JOIN MATCHES m 
    ON m.playerno = p.playerno
 WHERE p.town = 'Manchester'
 GROUP BY p.playerno 
HAVING COUNT(1) > 2
ORDER BY p.playerno
```

This assumes that the value of `matchno` isn't duplicated for the same player. That is, there won't be any two rows with the same values of the tuple `(playerno,matchno)`.

If we didn't have that guarantee, but we were guaranteed that `matchno` was non-null (at least on the rows we want to consider)... to get a count of the unique values of matchno, we could replace the aggregate `COUNT(1)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT m.matchno)`.

That's an example of just one approach. There are a couple others...

Another approach is to use a unique column (or set of columns), inequality comparisons, and multiple references to the `matches` table. And again assuming that we want to consider only unique value of `matchno` for a given player to be included in the count...

We can use a join operation, to restrict the rows returned to only those where there is another row in `matches` for the player that has a lower value of `matchno`.

```
SELECT p.playerno
  FROM players p
  JOIN matches m1  ON m1.playerno = p.playerno
  JOIN matches m2  ON m2.playerno = p.playerno AND m2.matchno > m1.matchno 
  JOIN matches m3  ON m3.playerno = p.playerno AND m3.matchno > m2.matchno 
 WHERE p.town = 'Manchester'    
GROUP BY p.playerno
ORDER BY p.playerno
```

Another approach is to use an `EXISTS` predicates, to perform a similar check. Does a there exist a row in matches for the player, where there exists another row in matches for the same player with greater value of matchno, ...

Something like this:

```
SELECT p.playerno
  FROM players p
 WHERE p.town = 'Manchester'
   AND EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1 
           FROM matches m1
          WHERE m1.playerno = p.playerno
            AND EXISTS 
                ( SELECT 1 
                    FROM matches m2
                   WHERE m2.player_no = m1.playerno
                     AND m2.matchno   > m1.matchno
                     AND EXISTS 
                         ( SELECT 1
                             FROM matches m3
                            WHERE m3.playerno = m2.playerno
                              AND m3.matchno  > m2.matchno
                         )
                ) 
       )
ORDER BY p.playerno
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'group by' and 'having'.

e.g,

```
SELECT 
    playerno
FROM 
    PLAYERS,
    MATCHES
WHERE 
    PLAYERS.playerno = MATCHES.playerno
    AND town = ‘Manchester’
GROUP BY
    playerno
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 2;
```